# Configuring SSL cipher suites for Jetty

Tags: ssl, encryption, jetty

I am trying to set the allowed ssl cipher suites for the embedded jetty server in my application. If I only use IncludeCipherSuites setting for SslContextFactory in the xml file setting for some reason when I run sslscan it only lists the ciphers for TLSv1.2 and not TLSv1.1 or TLSv1.0. I need to be able to have jetty use all three TLS versions. Is there anyway I can set the IncludeCipherSuites for Jetty so that I can set the list correctly.

Comment: What version of Jetty? and how are you using it? (jetty-distribution? embedded? or one of the jetty clients?)

Comment: I am using jetty-distribution 9.3.8

Comment: I am also having the same issue. I wonder how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Jetty 9.3.8 disables the SLOTH vulnerable ciphers that prevent proper encryption with the latest versions of Chrome (if you re-enable the SLOTH vulnerable ciphers you'll see [a broken padlock icon in Chrome](https://bugs.eclipse.org/486877)).

You'll want to setup a `${jetty.base}/etc/tweak-ssl.xml` and appropriate entry in your `${jetty.base}/start.ini`

> Note: you should be using a split `${jetty.home}` and `${jetty.base}` directory structure and **not** modifying the `${jetty.home}` contents

Documented here: https://eclipse.dev/jetty/documentation/jetty-9/index.html#configuring-sslcontextfactory-cipherSuites

As for what configuration to use, that's up to you decide.

Know that excludes win over includes.   If the cipher suite is excluded, no addition of it in the includes list will enable it.

> Also be aware, that the JVM itself is also disabling various old protocols and cipher suites, following the same guidelines and updated specs that Jetty is with regards to security.  In the near future you'll have to also re-enable those ciphers and protocols at the JVM level.