# java code or any java tool for combining jetty xml files ( like jetty-http.xml ) from old to new considering configuration from old file

Tags: xml, merge, jetty

Let's say if we have all the configuration set in jetty-http.xml and there's a new attribute in an element introduced in later version , code should take care of old configuration and merge it into new one!!

Any java code or tool

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be editing the `jetty-http.xml` that ships with the `jetty-home` archive.

There are ways to configure it with properties, and if you need to tweak the behavior in ways that are not present in the `jetty-home` artifact, you can use another XML, different in name from `jetty-http.xml`, in your `${jetty.base}/etc/` to tweak the default behavior using the object ID present in the XML.

See past answer for this behavior.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36608943/775715

Comment: To make myself clear, we have j2 templates of xml files like jetty-http.xml, jetty-threadpool.xml , webapp-common.xml, etc  and these files are under <jetty-home>/etc/ folder , if one configures these files such that jetty-http.xml having multiple connectors , jetty-threadpool having multiple threadpool and on later version of our software , we add acceptQueueSize in the jetty-http.xml template and we want this to be in every connector , Can this be automated with any tool or java code ?

Comment: That scenario does not require modifications of any content in jetty-home to support.  Extra XML files can accomplish all of that and more.  It is important to understand that you should treat *all* content in jetty-home as read-only and don't change / touch / edit / remove / delete / rename / etc anything in that directory tree.   If you are building a product on top of jetty-home, then you want to use an jetty include interim directory which sits between jetty-home and your users jetty-base.  (eg: jetty-home :: product-home :: jetty-base)